# How do I connect 2 routers where only the second router does the PPPoE?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, home-networking

I have a broadband connection and the only good FTTH ISP in my town has left me with a [PON (passive optical network) port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_optical_network), instead of the usual Ethernet endpoint connection.

There aren't a lot of good routers that come with a PON port so I was left with a router that my ISP provided - it doesn't even have a name, and it is very buggy, drops connection very often when more than 1 device is connected to the Wi-Fi network. I have checked for PON to LAN adapters but they are ridiculously expensive.

I already have a normal NETLINK HG323RGW router which works. It has 2 RJ45 ports and a PON port. The FTTH PON plug given by my ISP is connected to the PON port on the router. It has an option to enable PPPoE proxy. Offers 2 modes: route, and bridge mode. Currently connected over route mode. It supports VLAN as well.

Is there a way to set the primary PON router to just forward the "connection" such that my secondary TP-Link handles all the PPPoE, DHCP, Wi-Fi etc.? I want my primary router to just sit and act as a dummy device that does the job of converting the PON port to LAN port - that is, the PON router should not handle DHCP, PPPoE, it should just act as an input for PON port, but my secondary NETLINK router should handle the DHCP, PPPoE, and networking.

These are my current router settings:

[image: Screenshot of router settings.]

Comment: Can you clarify "_ridiculously expensive_"? (Does £50-£100 count?)... What you're likely after is an appropriate SFP, paired with a "Media Converter" that supports SFP to RJ-45 (e.g: 802.3ab). Who is your ISP, and do you have more details on the fibre connection? (wavelength, multi-mode/single-mode, etc...)

Comment: @Attie The SFP to RJ-45 media convertors are very scarce and are not in stock at the moment here (I'm from India), and the ones that are, have increased their prices due to the shortage because of the pandemic. They are selling them at around 10,000 Rupees (around £100), which is expensive for me.

Answer (score 4):

## What you’re looking for is bridged mode.

That way, whatever traffic arrives via the optical network is pushed out unaltered (except sometimes VLAN filtered) on the Ethernet side and vice versa.

Not all routers support this. You cannot always enable it yourself, the ISP may have to do it. Your ISP may use some proprietary authentication scheme (other than PPPoE or whatever) that your TP-Link router doesn’t support out of the box. You may need the credentials for this authentication scheme.

Without further information about your current fibre router’s make and model (which it absolutely does have, check the label) and your ISP, the exact steps involved cannot be determined.

---

Upon checking the net for information about the NETLINK HG323RGW, setting up bridged mode appears to be fairly straightforward. Just edit the existing WAN connection and set its mode to “Bridged” instead of routed. You *should* then be able to use the same connection details on your second router. I *think* VLAN filtering is still performed on the NETLINK HG323RGW even in bridged mode. However, information is scarce, so you’ll have to figure that out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, networks work fine without "names", IPs are all you need! ;)

What kind of signal do you (does your ISP router) get from your ISP? What kind of router did you get from your ISP? It has an optical connection a WLAN-AP you said that, what else? Does it have an Ethernet port as well (I assume that's what you mean by LAN port)? What configuration is possible? Does it support "some kind" of PPPoE pass through? If not you'll probably need to use "DHCP/IPoE" in some form.

Without more information I can just "guess":

- If possible turn off "all" the "on top" routing/connectivity functionality in your ISP's router like NAT, DHCP, WLAN etc. and turn on PPPoE pass through (or whatever is available through your ISP's router and can be handled by your NETLINK router)
- Connect ISP's router to your NETLINK router via cable to the WAN port
- Configure your NETLINK router to access the PPPoE signal you get from your ISP's router (or whatever signal your ISP's router can provide) and do all the routing and connectivity over your NETLINK router

If you have more specific info in your question I can give you a more specific answer ;)

PS. Depending on what comes out of your ISP's router you might need to use the correct PPPoE credentials and setup the correct VLAN tag.